# Xamarin Forms Frame not expanding with content

Tags: user-interface, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms, and I've met my first challenge. I want a Frame around my Stacklayout within a Listview. When the user selects an item in the Listview I want some controls to appear. This works fine without the Frame, but the Frame does not expand when the controls appear. How can I change or get around this behavior?
Code below.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTest"
         x:Class="MVVMTest.MainPage">
<StackLayout>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Black">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Details}" IsVisible="{Binding ShowDetails}"></Entry>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

XAML.cs

```
namespace MVVMTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            BindingContext = new ViewModel()
            {
                Items = new List<ViewModelItem>()
                {
                    new ViewModelItem()
                    {
                        Name = "Test",
                        Details = "details"
                    },
                    new ViewModelItem()
                    {
                        Name = "Test2",
                        Details = "details2"
                    }
                }
            };
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace MVVMTest
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ViewModelItem _selectedViewItem;
        private List<ViewModelItem> _items;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ViewModelItem SelectedViewItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedViewItem;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedViewItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value.ShowDetails = !value.ShowDetails;
                    SelectedViewItem = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public List<ViewModelItem> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {

        }
    }

    public class ViewModelItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _showDetails;
        private string _details;
        private string _name;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool ShowDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return _showDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                _showDetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Details
        {
            get
            {
                return _details;
            }
            set
            {
                _details = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you added verticaloption= FillandExpand?

Comment: I tried that, yes. It works fine if the contents are already in the Frame when the page loads, but if the UI changes because of the databinding, the Frame simply does not expand

Comment: I wrote a demo based on your code and it works all right. Would you post the code of changing UI?  Or the while demo code, so that we can test it for you.

Comment: You have to use custom Editor Control. It will expend according to data. If you need it i can post code. You try or let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the PropertyChanged event to react to when the ListView was displayed or hidden. In the eventhandler, I set the HeightRequest of the Frame and this forces it to resize itself.

Alternative solution/help can be found here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/366577

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="Black" Margin="2" Padding="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailObjects}" IsVisible="{Binding ShowDetails}" PropertyChanged="ListView_PropertyChanged">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <Entry Text="{Binding Details}"></Entry>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new ViewModel()
        {
            Items = new List<ViewModelItem>()
            {
                new ViewModelItem()
                {
                    Name = "Test",
                    DetailObjects = new List<ViewModelItemDetails>
                    {
                        new ViewModelItemDetails
                        {
                            Details = "details1"
                        },
                        new ViewModelItemDetails
                        {
                            Details = "details2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ViewModelItem()
                {
                    Name = "Test2",
                    DetailObjects = new List<ViewModelItemDetails>
                    {
                        new ViewModelItemDetails
                        {
                            Details = "details1"
                        },
                        new ViewModelItemDetails
                        {
                            Details = "details2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListView_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is ListView list)) return;
        if (e.PropertyName == ListView.IsVisibleProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            Element parent = list;
            Frame frame = null;
            while (frame == null && parent != null)
            {
                if (parent is Frame) frame = parent as Frame;
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }

            if (list.IsVisible)
            {
                list.HeightRequest = list.ItemsSource.Cast<ViewModelItemDetails>().Count() * 50;

                if (frame != null) frame.HeightRequest = list.HeightRequest + 50;
            }
            else
            {
                if (frame != null) frame.HeightRequest = 50;
            }
        }
    }
}
```